# antlr string parser rule takes precedent over other rules

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the following grammar:

```
cell
    : operator value
    ;

operator
    : EQ
    ;

value
    : StringCharacters
    ;

EQ
    : '='
    ;

StringCharacters
    :   StringCharacter+
    ;
fragment
StringCharacter
    :   ~[\\\r\n]
    ;

WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip
    ;
```

The idea is to allow the following inputs:

```
= 3
=3
=asdkfljer
=skdfj wkrje slkjf
```

and so on and have the parser recognize the preceding operator all the time. But that's exactly not what is happening. Instead, the parser always recognizes everything as a value.

How can I implement the grammar in such a way that the parser always recognizes the operator first and basically accepts the rest as the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `StringCharacters` matches any of your input string and ANTLR takes a token with the greatest length possible.

To solve this I'd suggest using [Lexical Modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md), something like:

```
EQ
    : '=' -> pushMode(VALUE_MODE)
    ;

mode VALUE_MODE;

StringCharacters
    :   StringCharacter+ -> popMode
    ;

fragment
StringCharacter
    :   ~[\\\r\n]
    ;

WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip
    ;
```

Note, the example above will be able to parse only one line.

If you want to parse multiple lines of values, you have to modify the lexer and the parser:

Lexer:

```
EQ
    : '=' -> pushMode(VALUE_MODE)
    ;

mode VALUE_MODE;

StringCharacters
    :   StringCharacter+ [\r\n]* -> popMode
    ;

fragment
StringCharacter
    :   ~[\\\r\n]
    ;

WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip
    ;
```

Parser:

```
cell
    : (operator value)*
    ;

operator
    : EQ
    ;

value
    : StringCharacters
    ;
```